# do while loop with find function error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple loop with a find function inside and a counter in the find function. It works the first time through the loop, but when I increase the counter it give me an error. Can someone tell me what's wrong?? Thanks!

```
Dim a as integer
a=1
do while (a<1135)
Range("A:A").find(a).select
....
a=a+1
loop
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and on what line of code are you getting it?

Comment: I'm guessing there is no "2" in column A

Comment: that's what I'm thinking too, but I'm trying to prod him so his question doesn't get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: column A goes from 1 to 1136. I get an error on "Range("A:A").find(a).select" line the second time it's going through the loop. I know it's the second time because I'm basically copying and pasting to a different sheet and it does that correctly for the number "1"

Comment: the error message I get is......

Comment: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Why are you finding incremental numbers?  Would a loop be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, I'd recommend sticking with [Microsoft's Sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for `.Find`. Then you shouldn't have any problems with numbers not found:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim rng As Range

a = 1
Do While (a < 1135)
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(a)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Sheets(1).Activate
        rng.Select
        ...
    a = a + 1
Loop
```

Comment: "select method of range class failed"

Comment: Is the sheet hidden or protected and some cells cannot be selected? Maybe if you first `Activate` the sheet in question? What's the result when you type in the direct window `? rng.Address` (while in debugging mode)?

Comment: Also, why are you selecting the range? What are you planning to do with it? You'll need to use a `Union` to add each newly found cell to `rng`. Lots of info about that on this site.